# Can SonarQube analyse T-SQL stored procedures for Microsoft SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, sonarqube

I got a new task as follows:

1. Export stored procedures on a daily basis from db
2. Run them through sonarqube to analyze

I am not a db expert but working in DevOps team. Can anyone tell me if SonarQube supports the analysis of T-SQL stored procedures? If not, which tool does? I see only PL/SQL here in the supported language list: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library

Answer (score 2):

This one looks promising

https://github.com/gretard/sonar-tsql-plugin

(still in beta version as of now)

Comment: There is now an official analyzer for T-SQL
https://www.sonarsource.com/products/codeanalyzers/sonartsql.html

Comment: Awesome! Its been waited for a long time

Answer (score 1):

All plugins supported by SonarQube team & community are listed in documentation: http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Library

You should search for plugins by other companies. I found only [TechCognia's TSQL Plugin](http://www.techcognia.com/TSQL.aspx).