# SonarCloud Analyse SQL Server SSDT Project

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, sonarqube, azure-devops, sonarcloud

I'm trying to analyse a SQL server SSDT database project with SonarCloud but running into some issues.

We are using VSTS with the SonarCloud tasks set up around the build to listen, build, analyse and publish to our SonarCloud account.

[image: Build Process]

It runs successfully but doesn't scan all the project, it scans and analyses a few stand-alone .SQL files recognising them as t-sql files but none of the actual stored procedures.

Please can anyone help on how to include the stored procedures in the code analysis?

Many Thanks

Comment: See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682038/can-sonarqube-analyse-t-sql-stored-procedures-for-microsoft-sql-server) SO question. Why do you think the plugin needed is installed in SonarCloud?

Comment: What's the result like? (Code tab) What's the result you want? A simple result: https://sonarcloud.io/code?id=sqlteststarain&selected=sqlteststarain%3AAzureDatabaseSolution%2FSQLDatabase

Comment: @JeroenHeier Thanks for the reply. I think the plugin is installed already because its analysing some of the .sql scripts (stand-alone one time run scripts), but not any of the stored procedures, which I dont understand why.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT thanks for the reply. The result in the Code tab looks to pick up the database folder, and a couple of additional folders underneath. However the main schema "dbo" folder is not being picked up, which contains the bulk of the stored procedures. We removed the .sql extension type from the PL/SQL language selection and added it to the TSQL language selection, and can confirm the code which is being picked up is being analysed as TSQL.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - from the example you linked to a similar situation would be where the Script.PostDeployment1.sql has been picked up but prorcedure1.sql is not.

Comment: The Lines of Code value is 6 for procedure1.sql. What do you want it like? Regarding "We removed the .sql extension type from the PL/SQL language selection and added it to the TSQL language selection", how do you do it?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - I don't think I understand your question about what I want it like? I want all the lines of code in my project to be analysed (I dont know how many there are). It appears SonarCloud is not analysing 99% of the project. To change .sql extension pickups for different languages its just done through the settings in SonarCloud itself.

Comment: In the sample result, the Line of Code value is 6 for procedure1.sql file, so I think the file has been analysised, Am I right?

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - Yes you are correct

Comment: So, it is working fine for me. What're tasks of your build definition? (My build definition: 1. Prepare Analysis Configuration (Use standalone scanner option; Manually provide configuration; Source Directory root: `.`) 2. Visual Studio Build 3. Run Code Analysis 4. Publish Analysis result.

Comment: @starianchen-MSFT - I have added an image above

Comment: Can you reproduce this issue with a new simple project? If so, you can share the sample project on the OneDrive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to this. The MSBuild SonarCloud integration doesn't work for database projects, you have to use the Sonar Scanner option when configuring the listener task.

Edit: after getting in touch with SonarCloud they have raised the issue and provided a workaround which you can find via the link below

https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-msbuild/issues/463